# Need to serialize Aerospike Lua Map<Map<Map<>>>

Tags: c, lua, aerospike, jnlua

We have a Lua `Map<Map<Map<>>>`  structure in Aerospike .

We want to compress this structure, and in order to do that we need to serialize it. Any pointers about how to go about this?

Comment: Can you expand on what you're doing? If this is a record UDF what is the structure of the data in the record? Is this a stream UDF? What are you trying to do when you're calling the UDF from the client?